# Trying to create a Nim-Nim dll, to be able to work with plugins, but tests keep crashing

Tags: dll, plugins, nim-lang

Creating a Nim only dll is hardly documented.  I'm creating an addon for a simulator (3rd party) with plugins based on the spacecraft being flown.  Every 'spacecraft' module would only have 3 procedures that can be called by the main speech generating program.

Let's keep it a very simplified example:

```
type
  Settings: tuple
    datafolder: string
    spacecraft: string
type
  Speak: tuple
    who: string
    timetospeak: float
    whattosay: string
  
type
  MissionData: tuple
    missiontime: float
    position: array[3, float]
    velocity: array[3, float]
    callmessage: string
    speechQ: seq[Speak]
```

In whatever 'spacecraft' module we would have these same 3 callable procs:

- `initModule(s: Settings): bool`
- `speakModule(md: MissionData): MissionData` (so returns the altered MissionData)
- `endModule()`

So when flying SpaceXDragon or BoeingStarliner or SpaceShuttle the call remains the same, but the returned speechQ would not, because of the difference in procedures and handling of the various spacecraft.  Because of those differences and future options to use different languages, a text data file is loaded and turned into a hash table during initModule.

Typically, a call would be made to speakModule, which would add things to say in speechQ (based on mission data and callmessage) for the main program to process with text-to-speech.

All code I've produced either crashes as soon as a call is made, or in the best case when I'm iterating over the data file.  It's a memory issue caused by garbage collection, where main caller and called module don't agree on memory management.  But my tries to get them to work together fail miserably.

My tries are based on

- https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/1400 (uses nimcall
- https://peterme.net/dynamic-libraries-in-nim.html (uses cdecl, compiles noMain, orc, useNimRtl)
  The first got me furthest (crash on iterating over text data file), the other on calling any proc in the module.

I think using .nimcall. instead of .cdecl. would mean it's possible to just pass MissionData without nim/c parsing problems, determining size etc..  At least I hope so, I just never wrote a dll before.

Does anyone have an example of a **complete** framework that works ?  The info I found just seems to miss that final touch to make it really work. They point in the right direction, but implemented in real world situations, they break.

I created a minimum test based on https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/1400 which seemed to work.  But as I created a bigger text file for the lookup table, it crashed iterating over it:
**SIGSEGV: Illegal storage access. (Attempt to read from nil?)**

On the nim forum they pointed me to https://peterme.net/dynamic-libraries-in-nim.html, making me compile differently and implementing **proc NimMain()** in the module, called from initModule, right after the module loads successfully in the main program.

`nim c -mm:orc --threads:on -d:useNimRtl TESTmain.nim`

`created NimRtl.dll with nim c -mm:orc -o:NimRtl.dll <path-to>NimRtl.nim`

`nim c -mm:orc -d:useNimRtl --noMain --app:lib TESTmodule.nim`

This evening I did some more research and testing and have two not too big programs (DLLcaller and DLLmodule) to illustrate the issue.

```
# DLLmodule : to be called by DLLcaller
import strformat
import strutils
import sequtils
import tables
import random

import DLLtypes
import DLLfilereader



var
  # lookup table with simple speech (words or sentences) found in data-<language> currently only 'en' is implemented
  # in data file starts with TXT_ to extract to this table
  textTable* = initOrderedTable[string, string]()
  index: string
  initialized: bool = false
  countR: int

proc uncomment*(s: string): string =
  # strip comments (start with //) from string
  var commentpos = s.find("//")
  if commentpos == 0:   # found at start
     return ""
  elif commentpos > 0:
     return s[0..commentpos-1].strip()
  else:
     return s


proc loadSpeechData*(project:string = "", folder: string, language: string = "en") =
  # project is not used in this TEST version, just fixed TEST-en.txt (later to become <project>-en.txt)
  var
    speechData: string = ""
    resourceFilename: string = "TEST-en.txt"

  debugEcho(fmt("Loading speech data from {resourceFilename}\n"))
  try:
    speechData = readFile(resourceFilename)
  except:
    debugEcho(fmt("- ERROR : could not find speech data file {resourceFilename}\n"))
    quit()
  debugEcho("---------------------------------------")
  debugEcho("DUMP speechData:")
  debugEcho(" - size:   ", (sizeof(speechData)))
  debugEcho(" - length: ", (speechData.len))
  debugEcho(" - lines:  ", (speechData.countLines))
  debugEcho(speechData)

  # clear the data
  textTable.clear

  for d in speechData.splitLines():
    inc countR
    let dataLine = d.uncomment
    debugEcho(fmt("READ {countR:4d}|{dataLine}"))
    
    if dataLine.startsWith("TXT_"):
      # simple text (words or phrases)
      let s = dataLine.split(':')
      if s.len > 1:
         index = s[0].replace("TXT_", "")
         if not textTable.hasKey(index):
            # does not exist : create
            textTable[index] = s[1]
  return

proc unloadSpeechData*() =
  textTable.clear

proc getTXT*(index: string): string =
  # get text from textTable
  if textTable.hasKey(index):
    return textTable[index]
  else:
    # returned string may sound weird in TTS, but otherwise tracing what goes wrong will be very difficult
    return fmt("|{index} not found| ")
 

# A)
# if "proc NimMain() AND the call to it (a bit lower) are comment out
# and compiled without --noMain (nim c -mm:orc --app:lib -d:useNimRtl --noMain <file>)
# the dllCall actually does something (but hangs after a while)
# (displays output, but hangs and has to be stopped with Control-C 
#
# B)
# with "proc NimMain() and the call to it in place
# and compiled WITH --noMain (nim c -mm:orc --app:lib -d:useNimRtl --noMain <file>)
# it crashes immediately on call to dllCall
# DLLcaller.exe
# Traceback (most recent call last)
# ---------------First call to the dll----------------
# C:\Users\Ivan\GoForReEntry\DLLcaller.nim(91) DLLcaller
# C:\Users\Ivan\GoForReEntry\DLLcaller.nim(79) loadDll
# SIGSEGV: Illegal storage access. (Attempt to read from nil?)
# Error: execution of an external program failed: 'C:\Users\Ivan\GoForReEntry\DLLcaller.exe '


proc NimMain() {.cdecl, importc.}


proc dllCall*(sim: SIM): SIM {.exportc, dynlib.} =
  if not initialized:
#    NimMain()      
    debugEcho("Entered dllCall & Initialized by call to NimMain(), if it wasn't commented out...")
    initialized = true
    # if compiled with "nim c -mm:orc --app:lib -d:useNimRtl --noMain DLLcalled01" and NimMain is called : crashes immediately on call to dllCall
    # if compiled with "nim c -mm:orc --app:lib -d:useNimRtl DLLcalled" and NimMain is commented out: it runs for a while before crashing
    # the main calling program is compiled with "nim c -r -mm:orc -d:useNimRtl DLLcaller"
    # NimRtl is compiled with 


  var simReturn = sim
  # test : add 1/10 as many SPK elements as there already are
  # but minimum 1 and maximum 20
  var i = (sim.spk.len div 10) + 1
  if i > 20:
    i = 20
  var x: int
  while x < i:
    var s: SPK
    s = ("Paul", fmt("Hi {(simReturn.spk.len):04d}"), 1100.0 + x.toFloat)
    simReturn.spk.add(s)
    x += 1
    if simReturn.spk.len == 1000:       # we've been busy a while, time to load the text file into a hash table
      loadSpeechData("", "", "en")
 
  
  # if there are more than 100 items, delete one randomly
  if simReturn.spk.len > 100:
    simReturn.spk.del(rand(99))


  # if more than 1000 lines : insert something from the text file
  if simReturn.spk.len > 1000:
    let el = rand(500)
    simReturn.spk[el].whatText = simReturn.spk[el].whatText & getTXT((fmt("{el:03d}")))


  return simReturn
```

```
# DLLcaller (will call DLLmodule)
# test to see if dll causes crash
# compile with nim c -mm:orc -d:useNimRtl <file>

import os
import dynlib
import sequtils
import strformat
import strutils
import random

import DLLtypes



var
  r: int
  firstCall: bool = true


type dllCall = proc (sim: SIM): SIM {.stdcall.}


proc createTestfile() =
  # create a 500 line test text file
  var txt: string
  for i in 1..500:
    let r = rand(i)
    txt = txt & (fmt("TXT_{i:3d}:Line {i} with random number: {r}.\n"))

  try:
    writeFile("TEST-en.txt", txt)
  except:
    debugEcho("Could not write test file")

proc modifySpeech(s: SIM): SIM =
#  for i in 0..100:
#    echo(fmt("GC {i:5d}"))

  var
    sim = s
  # remove something
  r = rand(sim.spk.high)
  if r > 10:
    if sim.spk[r].whatText.contains("----"):
      sim.spk.del(r)

  # modify something at random (text in the seq)
  r = rand(sim.spk.high)
  if r > sim.spk.high div 10:
    sim.spk[r].whatText = sim.spk[r].whatText & "-ADDED-IN-CALLER-"

  return sim   


proc loadDll() =
    randomize()

    # Load library
    let lib = dynlib.loadLib("DLLmodule.dll", true)
    assert lib != nil, "Error loading library"

    # Prepare function
    let dllCall = cast[dllCall](lib.symAddr("dllCall"))
    assert dllCall != nil, "Error loading function"

    # Prepare variables
    var sim: SIM
    sim.timeA = 0000.0
    sim.timeB = 1234.5
    sim.spk = @[("Pete", "Hello, I'm Pete", 1010.1)]

    # loop calling the proc in the dll until we have a large number of spk elements
    while sim.spk.len < 9000:      # do enough to use memory so the garbage collector will have work

       if firstCall:               # to check whether crash on first call, or later?
         firstCall = false
         debugEcho("---------------First call to the dll----------------")

       sim = dllCall(sim)          # let the dll modify the SIM data
       sim = modifySpeech(sim)     # modify SIM data here
   
    # Show output
    var i: int
    for s in sim.spk:
     i += 1
     echo(fmt("{i:05d} {s.whatTime:8.1f} {s.who:6s} {s.whatText}"))

    # Unload library
    unloadLib(lib)

loadDll()
```

Smaller programs, that don't use memory much, seem to do fine (if compiled without --Nomain).